# Handsontable make newly inserted cell editable while already loaded cell with value readonly

Tags: jquery, cell, readonly, handsontable

I am using `handsontable` to load values and edit those.

I have a table as follows:

```
 var cw = document.getElementById('tableorder').clientWidth;
                        var rest = cw - 550;
                        var container = document.getElementById('tableorder');
                        ordertable = new Handsontable(container, {
                            data: data,
                            colHeaders: ['Collection Mode', 'Remarks','Amount'],
                            columns: [
                                {data: 4, readOnly: false, type: 'autocomplete', source: collectionmethod, validator: collectionmethod_validations, strict: true},
                                {data: 5, readOnly: false},
                                {data: 3, readOnly: false, type: 'numeric', format: '0.000', validator: qty_validations, allowInvalid: true}
                            ],
                            minSpareRows: 1,
                            rowHeaders: true,
                            contextMenu: ['row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row', 'undo', 'redo'],
                            colWidths: [250, rest, 250],
                            autoWrapRow: true,
                            autoWrapCol: true,
                            beforeRemoveRow: removerow_validation
                        });
```

I have a certain set of values from ajax and I am creating table:

What I need is:

I need to make  certain cells `read-only`. But If I insert another row then the new row containing  that particular cell should be editable

In my case I need the following cell to be `read-only`

```
{data: 3, readOnly: false, type: 'numeric', format: '0.000', validator: qty_validations, allowInvalid: true}
```

I tried by giving  `readOnly: false` but if I add  new row then also it becomes readonly.

**How can I make already loaded cell read-only and newly inserted cell editable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution:

```
cells :function(row, col, prop) {
                                    var cellProperties = {};

                                    if (row < total_length) {
                                        cellProperties.readOnly = true;

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        cellProperties.readOnly = false;
                                    }

                                        return cellProperties;
                                }
```

Comment: Exactly, you can do a per-cell definition to achieve your answer.